lua AMS8 codigo lua
Alguém sabe como fazer um código lua para o AMS8 que verifique se o mouse está se mexendo? preciso fazer um código que verifica isso, para uma função funcionar somente quando o mouse estiver se mexer, quando parar ai ele vai chamar outra função.

Para evitar descentralização de orientações o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas ainda está disponível na sua pergunta original
